# Error creating new host: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field Driver.Virtio9p

Tags: minishift

After downloading minishift, I cant run it due to the following error,

```
Starting Minishift VM .... FAIL E0529 13:00:23.325175   82884 start.go:494] Error starting the VM: Error creating new host: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field Driver.Virtio9p of type []string. Retrying.
```

The [solution provided here does not help](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/issues/2380)

Below is the whole log.

```
Isaacs-MacBook-Pro-2:minishift-1.34.0-darwin-amd64 isaack$ minishift start
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... SKIP
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'xhyve' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if xhyve driver is installed ... 
   Driver is available at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-xhyve
   Checking for setuid bit ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'xhyve' hypervisor ...
-- Minishift VM will be configured with ...
   Memory:    4 GB
   vCPUs :    2
   Disk size: 10 GB
-- Starting Minishift VM .... FAIL E0529 13:00:23.325175   82884 start.go:494] Error starting the VM: Error creating new host: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field Driver.Virtio9p of type []string. Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error creating new host: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field Driver.Virtio9p of type []string
```

Comment: i have same issue. uninstallation/installation of xhyve didn't work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your 1.34.0 version of [Minishift is currently tested against docker-machine-driver-xhyve version 0.3.3.](https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/getting-started/setting-up-virtualization-environment.html#for-macos) and [has compatibility issues](https://github.com/machine-drivers/docker-machine-driver-xhyve/issues/221) with the recently deployed docker-machine-driver-xhyve v0.4.0.

The solution for me was to uninstall the docker-machine-driver-xhyve 0.4.0 driver and install the old and tested 0.3.3:

https://github.com/machine-drivers/docker-machine-driver-xhyve/releases/tag/v0.3.3

```sh
$ brew uninstall docker-machine-driver-xhyve
$ brew edit docker-machine-driver-xhyve
```

Change the `tag:` and `revision:` references to:

```rb
class DockerMachineDriverXhyve < Formula
  desc "Docker Machine driver for xhyve"
  homepage "https://github.com/machine-drivers/docker-machine-driver-xhyve"
  url "https://github.com/machine-drivers/docker-machine-driver-xhyve.git",
      :tag      => "v0.3.3",
      :revision => "7d92f74a8b9825e55ee5088b8bfa93b042badc47"
  revision 2
```

brew install as usual:

```sh
$ brew install docker-machine-driver-xhyve
```

```sh
$ minishift start 
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'xhyve' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if xhyve driver is installed ...
   Driver is available at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-xhyve
   Checking for setuid bit ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'xhyve' hypervisor ...
-- Minishift VM will be configured with ...
   Memory:    4 GB
   vCPUs :    2
   Disk size: 20 GB
-- Starting Minishift VM ...................... OK
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramon, this did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, in MAc, is using `virtualbox` as --vm-driver , for minishift vm, instead of `driver-xhyve`.

```
za:~ za$ minishift start --vm-driver=virtualbox
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'virtualbox' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if VirtualBox is installed ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'virtualbox' hypervisor ...
-- Minishift VM will be configured with ...
   Memory:    4 GB
   vCPUs :    2
   Disk size: 20 GB
-- Starting Minishift VM ............................. OK
-- Checking for IP address ... OK
-- Checking for nameservers ... OK
-- Checking if external host is reachable from the Minishift VM ... 
   Pinging 8.8.8.8 ... OK
-- Checking HTTP connectivity from the VM ... 
   Retrieving http://minishift.io/index.html ... OK
-- Checking if persistent storage volume is mounted ... OK
-- Checking available disk space ... 1% used OK
-- Writing current configuration for static assignment of IP address ... OK
   Importing 'openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0'  CACHE MISS
   Importing 'openshift/origin-docker-registry:v3.11.0'  CACHE MISS
   Importing 'openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v3.11.0'  CACHE MISS
-- OpenShift cluster will be configured with ...
   Version: v3.11.0
-- Pulling the OpenShift Container Image
```